# Something to change

Tags: c++, class, vector, struct

as the title, i don't know how to convert this struct into a class?
Also i've another problem, how can i convert the array Sets[][] and top[] into vector?
I tried, but i have problem with editing in a vector of [i] position.

```
//*******************************
//  Class Kruskal               *
//*******************************
class kruskal
{
private:
    struct Edge {
        //Arco: vertice V -> vertice U : peso W
        int v, u, w;
        Edge(int v, int u, int w) : v(v), u(u), w(w) {}
        bool operator < (const Edge& c) const{
            if (w != c.w)
                return w < c.w;
            if (v != c.v)
                return v < c.v;
            return u < c.u;
        }
    };
    int n; //n. nodes
    int nre; //n. edges
    vector<Edge> edges; //vector contenente tutti gli archiì
    vector<Edge> tree; //Albero che conterrà tutti gli archi dell'MST

    int sets[100][10]; //matrice contente i sets (tagli)
    int top[100]; //supporto alla matrice dei sets
public:
    kruskal(){};
    ~kruskal(){ cout << "Grafo distrutto"; };
    void read_graph();
    void sort_edges();
    void algorithm();
    int find_node(int);
    void print_min_span_t();
};

//*******************************************
//  read_graph()                            *
//  Legge in input n, nre, e i vari archi   *
//*******************************************
void kruskal::read_graph()
{
    cout << "Algoritmo di Kruskal" << endl;
    cout << "Minimum Spanning Tree su Grafo non orientato e pesato" << endl << endl;
    cout << "-Inserire numero di nodi e numero di archi: ";
    cin >> n >> nre;
    int v, u, w;
    cout << "-Inserire vertice 1, vertice 2 e peso:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < nre; i++)
    {
        cin >> v >> u >> w;
        if (w != 0)
        {
            edges.push_back(Edge(v, u, w));
        }
    }
    //Print graph edges
    cout << endl << endl << "Archi del grafo:" << endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << " < " << edges[i].v
            << " , " << edges[i].u
            << " > " << edges[i].w << endl;

    }
}

//*******************************************
//  sort_edges()                            *
//  Ordina gli archi per peso con sort()    *
//*******************************************
void kruskal::sort_edges()
{
    sort(edges.begin(), edges.end());
    //Print graph edges
    cout << endl << endl << "Archi del grafo dopo l'ordinamento:" << endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << " < " << edges[i].v
            << " , " << edges[i].u
            << " > " << edges[i].w << endl;
    }
}

//***********************************************
//  algorithm()                                 *
//  Inizializza i sets (make-set)               *
//  Trova i sets dei due nodi (Find_node)       *
//  Controlla se i sets sono diversi (Findset)  *
//  Se si lo inserisce nel vector "tree" (MST)  *
//  E unisce i due sets (Union)                 *
//  Altrimenti "scarta" l'arco                  *
//***********************************************
void kruskal::algorithm()
{
    //Make-set
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        sets[i][1] = i;
        top[i] = 1;
    }
    cout << endl << "Avvio algoritmo di Kruskal:" << endl << endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++)
    {
        int p1 = find_node(edges[i].v);
        int p2 = find_node(edges[i].u);
        //Findset(p1) != Findset(p2)
        if (p1 != p2)
        {
            cout << "Arco preso nell'albero:"
                << " < " << edges[i].v << " , "
                << edges[i].u << " > " << endl << endl;
            //Union
            tree.push_back(Edge(edges[i].v, edges[i].u, edges[i].w));

            //Union two sets
            for (int j = 1; j <= top[p2]; j++)
            {
                top[p1]++;
                sets[p1][top[p1]] = sets[p2][j];
            }
            top[p2] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Questo arco"
                << " < " << edges[i].v << " , "
                << edges[i].u << " > " << "forma un ciclo ed e' stato rimosso" << endl << endl;
        }
    }
}

//*******************************************
//  find_node()                             *
//  Trova il sets di appartenenza del nodo  *
//*******************************************
int kruskal::find_node(int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= nre; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= top[i]; j++)
        {
            if (n == sets[i][j])
                return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

//*******************************
//  print_min_span_t()          *
//*******************************
void kruskal::print_min_span_t()
{
    cout << endl << "Minimum Spanning Tree del grafo:" << endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tree.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << " < " << tree[i].v
            << " , " << tree[i].u
            << " > " << tree[i].w << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing you have to remember about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is that its contents is dynamic. Unless you tell it to contain `i` entries, or add `i` entries, it will be empty (or contain less).

Comment: "how to convert this struct into a class?" Just change its name to 'class whatever' and add the public/private access specifiers explicitly.

Comment: struct Edge is already in the private part of class krukal, so making it a class with private members won't be a big gain as long as Edge is mostly data used by krukal.

Comment: ok maybe, my problem now it's the array sets and top, that are "limited" if in input i give a big graph, how can i convert in vector?

Comment: Change int sets[100][10]; to vector<vector<int> > sets; and int top[100]; to  vector<int> top;

Comment: @user2672165: as `top[x]` is in fact `set[x].size()`, OP may remove completely `top`.

Comment: @claptrap I match your rule of three, and raise you a [rule of zero](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/rule-of-zero).

Comment: @rubenvb thanks for the link, it was interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `top` is just the size of corresponding `sets`, you may remove `top`, and change `std::vector<std::vector<int> > sets`.

Then

MakeSet:

```
//Make-set
sets.resize(nre); // or n, not sure of the definition of each one...
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != nre; ++i)
{
    sets[i].push_back(i);
}
```

UnionSet:

```
//Union two sets
sets[p1].insert(sets[p1].end(), sets[p2].begin(), sets[p2].end());
sets[p2].clear();
```

Find node:

```
int kruskal::find_node(int n) const
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i != sets.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (std::find(sets[i].begin(), sets[i].end(), n) != sets[i].end())
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: http://oi58.tinypic.com/x5pod1.jpg I've this error with insert... and i don't know why :(

Comment: What are the values of `p1` and `p2` ? I suspect Make-set should be `sets[i].push_back(1 + i);`

Comment: p1 and p2 are the values returned from find_node (then i or -1), ok with (i+1) it's work, thanks ;)